# preserve format while using regex replace in powerpoint VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint

```
Private Sub replaceCurrency()
Dim sld As Slide
Dim oSh As Shape
Dim last, start, i, X As Long
Dim trFoundText As TextRange, shpText As TextRange
Dim allMatches As Object, match As Object, RE As Object

Set sld = Application.ActiveWindow.View.Slide
Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

On Error GoTo Replace_in_Shapes_Error

With RE
    .Global = True
    .Multiline = False
    .ignorecase = True
    .Pattern = "([$€£¥])([ ])+(?=\d)" 'Checks for currencies with one or more following space(s)
End With

For Each oSh In sld.Shapes
    With oSh
    
        If .HasTextFrame Then
            Set shpText = oSh.TextFrame.TextRange
            Set allMatches = RE.Execute(shpText)
            For Each match In allMatches
                Debug.Print "txtfr:  " & match.submatches(0)
                Debug.Print "txtfr:  " & match.firstindex
                Set trFoundText = oSh.TextFrame.TextRange.Find(match.submatches(0))
                If Not (trFoundText Is Nothing) Then
                    start = match.firstindex
                    last = oSh.TextFrame.TextRange.Find(match.submatches(0)).Characters.Length
                    oSh.TextFrame.TextRange.Characters(start, last + 3).Select
                    HighlightWithBoxBorder
                End If
            Next
            
        ElseIf .Type = msoGroup Then

          For X = 1 To .GroupItems.Count
                If .GroupItems(X).HasTextFrame Then
                    If .GroupItems(X).TextFrame.HasText Then
                        Set shpText = .GroupItems(X).TextFrame.TextRange
                        Set allMatches = RE.Execute(shpText)
                        For Each match In allMatches
                            Debug.Print "txtfr+Grup:  " & match.submatches(0)
                            Debug.Print "txtfr+Grup:  " & match.firstindex
                            For i = 0 To (match.submatches.Count) - 1
                                Set trFoundText = oSh.TextFrame.TextRange.Find(match.submatches(i))
                                If Not (trFoundText Is Nothing) Then
                                    start = match.firstindex
                                    last = oSh.TextFrame.TextRange.Find(match.submatches(0)).Characters.Length
                                    oSh.TextFrame.TextRange.Characters(start, last + 3).Select
                                    HighlightWithBoxBorder
                                End If
                            Next i
                        Next match
                    End If
                End If
          Next X
        End If
    End With
Next oSh
```

> No loss on formatting while performing. All good. but except for executing grouped elements on the codeline ---> Set trFoundText = oSh.TextFrame.TextRange.Find(match.submatches(i)) ---> skipped its performing.

Need a help to get value in the above codeline for the grouped elements

Comment: Most likely, this is happening because you're formatting slides with local formatting. Instead, apply a font theme that uses your preferred fonts, apply those to the slide master and layouts, then reset the slides to ensure correct inheritance of formatting. Then find and replace will not change the formatting.

Comment: "While inserting that open and close tags into the existing content, its taking format from the first line of the para and spreading it to rest of the all contents." -You're inserting text, which is unformatted. So yes, it will take on the formatting if the paragraph. "Also as the slides will have multiple formats, it is too difficult to insist via master" - So you need to create layouts for the different types of slides. You'll always get better results if you program the way PowerPoint is built to work: http://www.brandwares.com/bestpractices/2017/01/powerpoint-construction-best-practices/

Comment: thanks a lot for your suggestion. I made corrections as above and need to fix a part of code

Answer (score 0):

```
Set trFoundText = .GroupItems(X).TextFrame.TextRange.Find(match.submatches(i))
If Not (trFoundText Is Nothing) Then
  start = match.firstindex
  last = .GroupItems(X).TextFrame.TextRange.Find(match.submatches(i)).Characters.Length
  .GroupItems(X).TextFrame.TextRange.Characters(start, last + 3).Select
  HighlightWithBoxBorder
End If
```